# C++, std::remove_if with std::string. Resize string by popping it's end in lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, iterator

Since `std::remove()` does not resize `std::string`, I've came up with an idea how to solve this:

```
std::string s{"aabcdef"};
std::remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [&s](char a)
    {
        if (a == 'a')
        {
            s.pop_back();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Excepted output:

> bcdef

Actual output:

> bcd

For some reason, it erases 4 characters instead of expected 2. If I try to pass an `int` instead and count **true** calls in lambda, it works as expected:

```
int removes{};
std::remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [&removes](char a)
    {
        if (a == 'a')
        {
                ++removes;
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
for (int i{}; i < removes; ++i) s.pop_back(); //s = "bcdef"
```

Comment: The `pop_back` gets called _before_ the `remove_if` can move anything around, not after. It sounds like you just want the erase-remove idiom. You can use [std::erase_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase2) in C++20, or write your own equivalent in C++17 or earlier.

Comment: Why not just use the iterator returned from `remove` and pass that to `erase`? `std::erase(std::remove(s.begin(), s.end(), 'a')), s.end())`

Comment: @AlanBirtles You want a member `s.erase()`. The non-member erase would be just `std::erase(s, 'a');`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the function/lambda you passed to `std::remove_if` isn't about what happened to the character you want to remove. It is about how to determine which character need to be removed. What that means is whatever happens within the lambda will happen before `std::remove_if` starting its removal algorithm.

In your case, since you called `pop_back()` within the lambda, you are actually removing the last letter before `remove_if` can identify which character need to be removed.

---

Another thing to note is, if `std::remove` doesn't actually remove, and your
usage should only call `pop_back()` twice, how come you end up with 3 characters, instead of 5?

The reason is because when you call the function `remove_if(begin_it, end_it, some_predicate)`, `some_predicate` will be invoked by every element between `begin_it` and `end_it`, regardless of what happens within `some_predicate`. Note that both iterators are determined before any calls of the predicate, so even when you did `pop_back()` within the predicate, `remove_if` will continue running the predicate after the last character.

In your case, since you have popped 2 characters, `remove_if` will actually run predicate on and shift both the null character and the character after the null character. In fact, if you run `s.size()`, you will notice the size is still 5 not 3.

---

To properly remove the characters, you should either use the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom):

```cpp
s.erase(std::remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [](char c){ return c == 'a'; }));
// or
s.erase(std::remove(s.begin(), s.end(), 'a');
```

Or for C++20 or later, you can use:

```cpp
std::erase_if(s, [](char c){ return c == 'a'; });
// or
std::erase(s, 'a');
```

Answer (score 3):

`std::remove()` doesn't really remove anything, it only moves the matching elements to the end of the range, and then returns a past-the-end iterator for the new end of the range.

To finally remove the characters from the string, you can call `string::erase()` specifying that iterator and the current end iterator to shrink the string to the reduced size:

```
std::string s{ "aabcdef" };

auto it = std::remove(s.begin(), s.end(), 'a');
s.erase(it, s.end());

std::cout << s << '\n';
```

---

If [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) is availabe, a very straightforward solution is to call [`std::erase()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase2):

```
std::string s{ "aabcdef" };
std::erase(s, 'a');

std::cout << s << '\n';
```

output:

```
bcdef
```

Comment: You need to mention that `std::erase` is available for strings only in C++20 and later.